# Decreasing Latency on App Similar to high frequency trading

Tags: website, ping, latency

I have a bot on a server that accesses information from a website at a very specific time. I want to minimize the time that it takes for their website to get my request and be the first person in line at that time, kind of like high frequency trading. Milliseconds make a big difference. I have thought about placing my server right next to theirs but am having difficulty figuring out where there server is located exactly. Any ideas on what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

You havent given much information, so its hard to give advice.

You are correct in that reducing physical distance will reduce latency.  Brokerages pay *a lot* of money to put their machines on the *same* network as the stock exchange.

You could put your server physically near their servers, as in the same city.  However, just because you are physically closer, that doesnt mean you are taking the shortest or fastest route.

Have you tried asking them where they are hosted?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wish I could but they dont want to reveal that information because I am not the owner. Is there any other way? If I did find out, how could I ensure that I am taking the shortest/fastest route?

Comment: If you know the IP, you could do a traceroute, so you could see the path